# shuold i use <nav> <a> or <nav> <ul> <li> <a> for navbar?

Tags: html, css

so i have been using `<nav> <ul> <li> <a>` for making a navbar but turns out i can use `<nav> <a>` to make navbar and when i use   its already inline so i don't use a lot of CSS. what do you guys think? note: I am self-taught so I don't know which one is right or someone to ask. Thank you, your answer will be appreciated

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Login</a>
  <a href="#">Register</a>
</nav>
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Login</a>
      <a href="#">Register</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ul li is used to easy control using css, especially dropdown menus. you are free to use nav a tags, if only one level of menu you have.

Comment: There was a long discussion about this on CSSTricks a few years ago. There were dissenters, but the consensus view was that for best accessibility, each link should be inside its own list item. There's certainly no value in putting all the links in a single list item.

Answer (score 1):

All of them: Use `<nav>` as a container, then a `<ul>` list with `<li>` children, and inside the `li` elements the actual links (`<a>`). That's good for accessibility AND SEO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display your navigation in a vertically displayed list, I would use the li tag.

If you want horizontal, I'd do it without them.

Ultimately it doesn't matter though. You can override the appearance of just about anything with CSS anyway.

Comment: if I use too much CSS doesn't that make my page slower or it doesn't matters?

Comment: Please always consider accessibility.